# Extract file and folders with specified permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions, tar

I pack a folder with lot of sub-folders and files in Windows with 7zip, upload to VPS and then run the command:

```
tar -xvzf file.tar.gz
```

then all unpacked files and folders have permissions of 777. How do I get it so that folders will have permissions of 755 and files 644?

Comment: There is a website called "Command Line Fu" that has lots of other ideas also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're running `tar(1)` as a regular user, it will apply your `umask` by default. If you're running `tar(1)` as `root`, then you can give `--no-same-permissions` command line option to ask `tar(1)` to respect the `umask`.

So: either run this as a regular user:

```
umask 022
tar zxvf file.tar.gz
```

or run this as `root`:

```
umask 022
tar zxvf file.tar.gz --no-same-permissions
```

You might want to stick `umask 022` into your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.profile`. (See `bash(1)` manpage for full details on the start up files. It's complicated.)

Details on `umask` can be found in your shell's manpage, the `umask(2)` system-call manpage, or the `umask(1posix)` POSIX-provided utility manpage (if you have the `manpages-posix` installed).

Comment: umask 022
tar zxvf file.tar.gz --> this asks me for confirmation for each file separately if I want to extract it

Comment: Are you over-writing existing files when doing so?

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands in the root of the directory to set the desired permissions for your directories and files:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Be aware of the space between the closing curly bracket and the back slash

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: any idea why this command says to me "find: missing argument to `-exec'"? Thanks.

Comment: Add a space between the closing curly bracket and the `\;`

Comment: xargs is faster

Answer (score 5):

If you use capital X in `chmod` you can use it to set the execute permissions only on directories. i.e.

```
chmod -R ugo+X .
```

Comment: short: `chmod -R +X .`

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution that worked for me. For folders and subfolders:

```
chmod -R 777 */
```

And for all files (also in folders and subfolders):

```
find . -type f -name "*" | xargs chmod 644
```

All comments welcome if this is not a good way of doing it. I just started learning Linux.

Following comments, a more robust solution that handles special characters nicely would be:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644  # For files
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755  # For directories
```

Comment: But the second command gives me on many files this output: chmod: cannot access `the': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `Logo.txt': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `./blog/wp-content/themes/OneRoom/LOGO': No such file or di
rectory

Comment: `777` is dangerous and only applicable to a very small minority of systems.

Comment: To improve upon your second command, `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644`. The `-name "*"` isn't necessary, and `xargs(1)` will parse filenames on _spaces_ or _newlines_ unless you use the `-0` -- which parses filenames on ASCII `NUL` character, which cannot appear in filenames. The `-print0` for `find(1)` asks it to format its output in a mode suitable for `xargs -0` input.

Answer (score 0):

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, please be advised 1 line answers are rarely accepted, can you elaborate more on your answer?